# List item with focusable accessory action using d-pad navigation

Tags: android, android-listview

On Android, a commonly used pattern in lists is the accessory action. This is often done by putting an extra button on the right of a list item.

For instance, the Alarm clock application lists the different alarm times; on each list item, an extra two-state button allows turning the alarm on or off without entering the alarm properties screen.
Such button is implemented by using a tweaked view that does not show itself pressed when the parent layout is.

One constraint in my project is that such actions should be selectable in non-touch mode i.e. while using d-pad navigation. Actually, only the main part of the list item can be used; it is not possible to focus on the accessory button using the d-pad. This happens on every proposed implementation on blog articles I have read.

A solution is to get rid of focusing the list item itself, but this implies losing much of the ListView or SettingsActivity features depending on the case.

Is it possible to make the extra button focusable in non-touch mode while keeping the normal ListView behaviour? What I want to achieve is, for example, to normally select a list item when using up/down and focus on the accessory button with the left/right keys.